# Alternating Square Pattern

Tags: materials, shaders

[image]

I realize this is a silly picture, but I'm interested in making the pattern in the background. With my current knowledge of the shader editor, I just come up short. I'm less interested in the color, though that is a plus, but I'm more interested in the shape. That slightly alternating square texture. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a voronoi node with a randomness of 0 and a mapping node to stretch along one axis:

[image]

Result:

[image]